# Need help creating restaurant menu. Base cost, toppings, tax, total are the outputs

Tags: python

Pretty much the title. Wrote some code but I don't know whats wrong with it as it won't run. I don't know if its even close to right. This program is a mac and cheese program, the user chooses between small, medium, and large and can add toppings. It has to spit out the toppings cost, base cost, and total cost with tax. I think I'm close, but I'm pretty fresh to this whole programming thing, so help a guy out. :)

```
#Lab 8 Mac and Cheese Program
#This program calculates the cost of ordered mac and cheese
#Date: 10/10/19

#Welcome Message
print ("Thank you for your purchase! This program will calculate the total cost of your order.")

print('-'*65)
print()

#Declare Variables
small = 4.00
medium = 5.00
large = 6.00
bacon = 1.50
grilled_onions = 1.00
grilled_chicken = 2.50
sloppy_joe = 2.50
lobster = 5.00

def mainMenu():
    print("1. Small    $4.00")
    print("2. Medium   $5.00")
    print("3. Large    $6.00")
    selection = int(input("What size Mac and Cheese would you like? Choose a number. ")
    if selection == "1":
        small()
    elif selection == "2":
        medium()
    elif selection == "3":
        large()
    else:
        print("Enter a valid selection" )
        mainMenu()

def small():
    small = 4.00
    print("You have ordered a small Mac and Cheese. ")
    toppings = str(input("Choose your toppings: ")
        def menu():
            print("1. Bacon             $1.50 ")
            print("2. Grilled Onions    $1.00 ")
            print("3. Grilled Chicken   $2.50 ")
            print("4. Sloppy Joe Meat   $2.50 ")
            print("5. Lobster           $5.00 ")
            print("6. No toppings             ")    
            choice = int(input("Enter the number for the topping you want. ")
                if choice == "1":
                    print("You have added Bacon to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "2":
                    print("You have added Grilled Onions to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "3":
                    print("You have added Grilled Chicken to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "4":
                    print("You have added Sloppy Joe Meat to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "5":
                    print("You have added Lobster to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 5.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "6":
                    print("You have chosen to add no toppings. ")
                    continue

                toppings_cost = choice
                print("The cost for all your toppings is" , toppings_cost)

                base_price = small
                print("The base price of your order is: ", base_price)


                tax = 0.06

                total_price = 0.06(choice + small)
                print("The total cost of your order is ", total_price)

                restart = input("Would you like to try another order? ")
                    if restart == "Yes"
                        mainMenu()
                    else:
                        print("Thank you for your order, have a great day!")
                            break

small()

def medium():
    medium = 5.00
    print("You have ordered a medium Mac and Cheese. ")
    toppings = str(input("Choose your toppings: ")
        def menu():
            print("1. Bacon             $1.50 ")
            print("2. Grilled Onions    $1.00 ")
            print("3. Grilled Chicken   $2.50 ")
            print("4. Sloppy Joe Meat   $2.50 ")
            print("5. Lobster           $5.00 ")
            print("6. No toppings             ")    
            choice = int(input("Enter the number for the topping you want. ")
                if choice == "1":
                    print("You have added Bacon to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "2":
                    print("You have added Grilled Onions to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "3":
                    print("You have added Grilled Chicken to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "4":
                    print("You have added Sloppy Joe Meat to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "5":
                    print("You have added Lobster to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 5.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "6":
                    print("You have chosen to add no toppings. ")
                    continue

                toppings_cost = choice
                print("The cost for all your toppings is" , toppings_cost)

                base_price = medium
                print("The base price of your order is: ", base_price)


                tax = 0.06

                total_price = 0.06(choice + medium)
                print("The total cost of your order is ", total_price)

                restart = input("Would you like to try another order? ")
                    if restart == "Yes"
                        mainMenu()
                    else:
                        print("Thank you for your order, have a great day!")
                            break

medium()

def large():
    large = 6.00
    print("You have ordered a large Mac and Cheese. ")
    toppings = str(input("Choose your toppings: ")
        def menu():
            print("1. Bacon             $1.50 ")
            print("2. Grilled Onions    $1.00 ")
            print("3. Grilled Chicken   $2.50 ")
            print("4. Sloppy Joe Meat   $2.50 ")
            print("5. Lobster           $5.00 ")
            print("6. No toppings             ")    
            choice = int(input("Enter the number for the topping you want. ")
                if choice == 1:
                    print("You have added Bacon to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "2":
                    print("You have added Grilled Onions to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 1.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "3":
                    print("You have added Grilled Chicken to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "4":
                    print("You have added Sloppy Joe Meat to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 2.50 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "5":
                    print("You have added Lobster to your order. ")
                    print("That will add 5.00 to the cost of your order. ")
                    more_toppings = str(input("Would you like any more toppings?" )
                        if more_toppings == "Yes":
                            menu()
                        if more_toppings == "No":
                            continue
                        else:
                            print("Invalid input, returning to toppings menu. ")
                                menu()

                elif choice == "6":
                    print("You have chosen to add no toppings. ")
                    continue

                toppings_cost = choice
                print("The cost for all your toppings is" , toppings_cost)

                base_price = large
                print("The base price of your order is: ", base_price)


                tax = 0.06

                total_price = 0.06(choice + large)
                print("The total cost of your order is ", total_price)

                restart = input("Would you like to try another order? ")
                    if restart == "Yes"
                        mainMenu()
                    else:
                        print("Thank you for your order, have a great day!")
                            break

large()

mainMenu()
```

Comment: *"it won't run"* - How specifically are you trying to run the code?  What happens when you try?  Is there an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?

Comment: It just crashes

Comment: Like it keeps popping up with some syntax error and crashes, but I dont know why its spitting out that error

Comment: *"some syntax error"* - There's an error message trying to tell you what and where the problem is.  You'll want to capture that information, don't just dismiss it.

Comment: after "if selection == 1:" it gives me an invalid syntax error, but i cant figure out what it is. I tried adding quotes, but like I said, I am new. I don't know what else to add

Comment: Yes, I just noticed these also. I'm currently running into an inconsistent spacing error which I'm trying to clean up

Answer (score 0):

You might find it helpful to start with a trimmed down version of your program and get that to work.  Just maybe "small."  Also, the "def menu()" function appears to be repeated for each size.  You might find it easier to work with/debug if you just have one "def menu()" that works more generally.  Lastly, you might want to watch out for "ints vs. strings" in your processing.  Hope that helps troubleshoot.